# How to make Flutter work without having to turn off AdGuard

Tags: flutter, dart

When I run `flutter doctor -v`, the following logs appear

```
⣽Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Future already completed
#0      _AsyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:43:31)
#1      _NativeSocket.startConnect.<anonymous closure>.connectNext.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:682:23)
#2      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1102:14)
#3      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1109:12)
#4      _NativeSocket.multiplex (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1130:11)
#5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

I tried searching and understood why here [#40515](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40515) & [70596](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70596).

That's because the flutter is blocked by AdGuard ([here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40515#issuecomment-714499891)).

But I wonder if it is possible that the flutter works well without having to disable AdGuard (maybe adding Flutter to whitelist by AdGuard?)

Thanks for all suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go `AdGuard Preferences -> Network -> Automatically filter applications -> Select Mode...` and change mode to `Automatic Proxy`.

Comment: thanks very much, it ran fine without having to disable AdGuard