# Unable to execute Flutter apps on macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, macos-big-sur

I recently upgraded to macOS Big Sur and then this error started to appear.

```
[PROJECT_NAME] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in PROJECT_NAME...             
Unhandled exception:

Bad state: Future already completed

#0      _AsyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:43:31)

#1      _NativeSocket.startConnect.<anonymous closure>.connectNext.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:682:23)

#2      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1102:14)

#3      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1109:12)

#4      _NativeSocket.multiplex (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1130:11)

#5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
pub get failed (255; #5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12))
exit code 255
```

My Flutter Doctor is:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on macOS 11.2.1 20D75 darwin-x64, locale en-AU)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
 
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

There is no effect after running this command:

```
flutter config --no-analytics
```

I also have uninstalled the Antivirus software to check if it's blocking and also verified that there is no firewall blocking the Flutter requests.

I have already checked these but with no success.

[Flutter Issue 68999 on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68999)

[Flutter Issue 71483 on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71483)

[MemoryTin | macOS Big Sur: Flutter doctor error](https://memorytin.com/2020/11/17/macos-big-sur-flutter-doctor-error-bad-state-future-already-completed/)

[StackOverflow | How to make Flutter work without having to turn off AdGuard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65564111/how-to-make-flutter-work-without-having-to-turn-off-adguard)

Is anyone facing a similar issue?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, any fixes avaialble?

Comment: @TapasPal, I agree it is so annoying. I had to switch to a different Mac for this. Still, Flutter is unusable in my old mac. :(

Answer (score 1):

> flutter upgrade -v

after , test this :

> flutter pub get